# How come some results can be derived if applying an equivalence trick afterwards but not before?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

i'm not sure how clear this question is, so let me try to explain a little more.

Let's say we have an integral (common example in physics etc.) on which a regularisation is applied. A regularisation process enables one to derive finite results when infinite results would be expected.

Another example more familiar (but not exactly equivalnt) is [L'Hopital rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), where a finite (determinate) result is obtained after manipulating an expression (using the derivatives) which originaly had an indeterminate result.

> The question is, how can this work (especially in the case where the
>   manipulation, either a limit process or sth else, can be equally
>   applied before but wrong results are derived).
>
> Is there any extra information that these manipulations add to the
>   original expression and so are able to derive results or sth else? Why
>   does the ordering (applying before or after) makes such a difference in most cases?

Thank you

Comment: I find your description of L'Hôptil's rule quite odd. It isn't so that the limit does not exist before you apply the rule, then suddenly it does after you apply it! If you apply the rule successfully, the limit existed all along – it was just harder to find before you applied the rule. As for the physics example, are you thinking of renormalization? If so, I think that is more of a physics question than about mathematics, though mathematics is certainly involved at some point. But again, it isn't a question of an infinite quantity becoming finite through some manipulation.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, well ok, L'Hopital example was added for familiarity, it i not an exact counterpart to what is aksed here (and the question tags are mere hints, there are not tags for what i would like to ask, like trick/manipulation or sth along these lines). The example form physics (it is regularisation, which is used as a step in renormalisation as well). If further clarification is needed, i would very much add it. "*How come it is easier after we apply the derivatives, what exactly (information-wise) changed in the original expression*" (sth along these lines)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure of what you mean with the example of the integrals, so I will discuss the example of the L'Hopital rule. For the sake of clarity, let us take an example with two function $f$ and $g$ satisfying:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = 1.
$$

As you know, this tells you that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$.

Of course you also know that you can't compute the limit just by taking the quotient of the two individual limits, because this would be an indeterminate form of type $\frac{0}{0}$. But this does not mean, as your question seems to imply, that computing $\frac{0}{0}$ is *wrong*. It just means that *it is not the answer to your problem*.

In other words, when you replace a functions with its limit you are losing information. The limit is just one little piece of data with respect to the whole sequence (although usually a pretty interesting one). It actually happens that knowing just the limits of the two functions ($0$ and $0$) does not contain enough information to say something on the limit of the quotient of the two functions. Technically you are not really doing something wrong, you are just dropping more information than you would like (which, in a sense, is wrong; but it is not "mathematically" wrong, if you understand what I mean).

In other cases retaining just the limits of the two functions is enough. For example, if you knew that the two limits were $1$ and $3$ that would be enough to say that the limit of the quotient is $\frac{1}{3}$.

So, what the L'Hopital rule tells you is that, although sometimes the two individual limits are not enough information to evaluate the limit of the quotients, the limit of the quotient of derivative functions may still be enough (not necessarily: it may not exist!).

This is not about a process that works after a certain operation and not before. It simply about doing different types of transformation to the data that you have, which can drop or retain the information you are interested into. In our case taking individual limits is dropping too much information, but taking the limit of the quotient of derivatives still encodes what you are searching.

I think the same applies to your example of integration, but since I do not understand what you mean I cannot discuss in detail.

Comment: +1, nice, yet we know that the limit of a quotient equals the quotient of the limits, how is this related to being able to derive a (determinate) result in 1st case but not in 2nd?

Comment: We know that the limit of the quotient is equal to the quotient of the limits *when the latter exists*. It may well happen that the limit of the quotient exists, but the quotient of the limits does not (which is the case that I described). In this case the theorem does not apply and does not give you any information. This is another way to describe the fact that you dropped the information you are searching.

Comment: hmmm, we can restrict the question to the case where the limits exist (but may be indeterminate in one case and determinate in the 2nd case)

Comment: If the limits of the functions exist but give rise to an indeterminate form (for example $\frac{0}{0}$), then the quotient of the limits does not exist, which is exactly the case that I was discussing. An indeterminate form is not something "bad", it just gives you no information on the limit of the quotient (which is what you want to find).